# Laravel blank white screen in deploy website

Tags: php, laravel, deployment, eloquent, web-hosting

Please, some help for deploy Laravel 5.2 website, in below error message in public_html/error_log :

> [21-Mar-2017 07:39:30 America/Chicago] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/home/exoweb/public_html/allos/bootstrap/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/opt/alt/php55/usr/share/pear:/opt/alt/php55/usr/share/php') in /home/exoweb/public_html/index.php on line 22

I succeeds to start my web site, by changing the index.php file in public_html

require **DIR**.’/../allos/bootstrap/autoload.php’;
$app = require_once **DIR**.’/../allos/bootstrap/app.php’;

BUT I have an error when my controller uses a request with Eloquent, by against it works very well with query builder!

Comment: Check permissions of the file. You may not have the permission to `read` the file.

Comment: What file I must check his permission?

Comment: check the permission for '\home/exoweb/public_html/allos/bootstrap/autoload.php'. It is also possible that this file is not present at all.

Answer (score 0):

run `composer update` in the application directory. Always run composer update when you move an application which has composer as its dependency manager.

Comment: Don't you have the shell access to your server? Or may be you have a cPanel where you can run that.

Comment: where or how can do that in cPanel?

Comment: There must be an option to that. I don't know which hosting you are using.

Comment: hosting fastcomet.com

Comment: You need the SSH access from this hosting provider. Then you will be able to do that. Below is the guide from fastcomet.com to achieve this. Have a look!

https://www.fastcomet.com/community/composer-available-on-shared-hosting-environment/

Answer (score 0):

Have you try to access your website like your-site-url/public?

If it is running successfully in public directory then you just have a problem of redirecting.

So, place this .htaccess file into your root directory.

If your application is built in php version 7 then use this .htaccess file.

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php70 .php
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

for rest of the php version<7, use this .htaccess file.

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php56 .php .php5 .php4 .php3 
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

If there are still errors and you dont have access on Ssh , maybe tray to delete the cache files :

Bootstrap : services.php, settings.php Delete

Storage/Framework/Cache Delete all files

Storage/Framework/session Delete all files

Storage/Framework/views Delete all files

And refresh the site.
good luck :)